How to add now() when creating a jsonb by ORM assigment
I have a table where a column is defined as: data = db.Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
Inside my code, I am trying to store the server transaction current_timestamp, doing the following: mymodel.data = {'a': text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')} but it fails with the error:
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) json cannot serialize this type: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
How can this be solved?

Does this answer your question?

@snakecharmerb unfortunately, it does not solve my problem as you are using core sqlachemy which also allows syntax like jsonb_set/.. to do this. My question is related for the ORM lawyer, where you cannot construct directly sql statement or core sqlalchemy sql statements.

It isn't possible to directly include func.now() or similar when assigning to a JSONB attribute because SQLAlchemy will try to serialise the the data to JSON before sending it to the database, and the function object is not serialisable.
One way around this would be to add an after insert event that updates the value with the timestamp, like this:
import sqlalchemy as sa

@sa.event.listens_for(MyModel, 'after_insert')
def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    "listen for the 'after_insert' event"
    stmt = (
        sa.update(MyModel)
        .where(MyModel.id == target.id)
        .values(
            data=sa.func.jsonb_set(MyModel.data, '{a}', sa.func.to_jsonb(sa.func.now()))
        )
    )
    connection.execute(stmt)

You could probably do the update immediately after adding the entity in your mainline code (you might need to flush the session first), but if this is something that you always want to do it's cleaner to put it in an event.

(Assuming that you are using PostgreSQL)

Yes, this is for PG.
